# How do I preview OBS (twitch like) livestream screen capture on sample html5 webpage on localhost ?

Tags: html, localhost, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, video-on-demand

I'm currently working over a livestream platform like Twitch and I still can't figure out how to pass the data captured from OBS (Open Broadcast Software) to localhosted HTML5 webpage.. I mean to visualize the stream.. If someone has been working in this areas I will be very thankful to help me or at least to give me the idea of how to do it.

Thanks in advance,

A friendly user. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the OBS default output format is RTMP so you will need a player that supports Flash RTMP input. There are a few free options out there such as JWPlayer.
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430349-about-rtmp-streaming

Here is a Wowza RTMP test player, too.
http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html